# Eclipse finds syntax errors that netbeans doesn't

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, syntax-error

I have recently switched from Netbeans to Eclipse, and Eclipse is finding syntax errors in my Project lot's of places that Netbeans doesn't and I cannot figure out why.  As far as can tell both IDE's are set to use java 1.6.  An example of this problem would be as follows (which is actually horrible code but I am working with legacy stuff):

```
Map map;
map = new Hashtable();

... add some stuff to map

int number = 5;
int status = 7;

assertTrue(number == map.get(status));
```

The above comes back with "Incompatable operand types int and Object" whereas Netbeans does not complain at all.  I do not actually following why this doesn't work (does the int object not get autoboxed to an Integer?) as it works at run time from Netbeans. I am presuming there is a configuration setting somewhere in eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like autoboxing is disabled. Check that Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings Boxing and unboxing conversion is not set to Error. Also check that Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE use JDK\JRE that is at least 1.5.

Comment: Boxing and autoboxing conversions are set to ignore and my JRE is java-6-sun-1.6.0.24, yet the error is still there

Comment: @mogronalol: you may have project specific settings. Right click your project and select Properties. Check here again the compiler settings under Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings.

Comment: Maybe somebody changes project's settings at the Netbeans to ignore this error.

Comment: Another possible reason is different vendors of JVM or what is more likely in your case different versions of the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup compiler-warnings under Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings.

Make also sure you're compiling against the correct Java Version (check if your 1.6 Java is in the build-path and check the JDK Compilance level, see Preferences->Java->Compiler)

Comment: Hm under Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings everything is set to either warning and ignore, and under Preferences->Java->Compiler I have the compiler compliance level set to 1.6 and the use default compliance settings box ticked.  Yet I am still getting "Incompatable operand types int and Object" with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration to

```
    Map<Integer,Integer> map;
    map = new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>();
```

and this will solve you problem.

Alternatively, you can change this line

```
    assertTrue(Integer.valueOf(number) == map.get(status));
```

Comparing Integer with == is not good practice. It is working just occasionally. You really should use equals() instead.

I don't why autoboxing in your case doesn't occurs automatically, maybe somebody that know spec better could provide answer.

P.S. Even better change this to

```
    assertEquals(number, map.get(status));
```

and this will work as expected.

**After clarifications that it is legacy code, my advice is the following. Change your code to:**

```
Map map;
map = new Hashtable();

... add some stuff to map

Integer number = Integer.valueOf(5);
Integer status = Integer.valueOf(7);

assertEquals(number, map.get(status));
```

(I would even define temporary variable of type Integer where I put result of `map.get(status)`, but it is question of the style whether to do this; This will help compiler though). Here, no *new* features is used.

Why you don't have problem with the Netbeans? My guess is because your version of JRE (or vendor) or your project settings.

Comment: @mogronalol, change last line to `assertEquals(number, map.get(status));` and it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I am aware that this code is poor and it is legacy code that I must work with. I know changing it to infer generic types arguments will work, but the problem is that there is no syntax error found in Netbeans whereas there is in Eclipse.  I just cannot get my head round why this occuring.

Comment: If it is legacy code it shouldn't compile. As of pre-JDK 1.5 `map.get(status)` returns Object and number is defined as primitive type (int). Operator == is not defined between int and Object, so you have to have compilation error. Furthermore, `map.get(status)`where status is primitive (int) shouldn't compile either, because `Hashtable.get()` receives Object.   Why you didn't have at the Netbeans, I don't know, may be it has something to do with your project settings (somebody changed them). The easiest way is as said to change your assert statement to `assertEquals(number, map.get(status));`

Comment: I also recommend you to use Integer instead of int. That is define status and number as Integer.

Comment: @mogronalol I edited my answer. Try the code above and tell whether it works. Check also version\vendor of JRE of Netbeans and project preferences.